# HTML pattern validation doesn't work in Chrome 57.0.2987.98

Tags: html, regex

The following input tag will allow less than five, lower-case characters.  From other SO posts, it should display the message in the title but, instead, allows the validation to pass with only one to four characters.

```
<input type="password" id="password" required pattern="[a-z]{5, 10}" name="password" title="5 to 10 characters" />
```

Comment: Try removing the space from the pattern, like this: `pattern="[a-z]{5,10}"` https://jsfiddle.net/nwsy391p/

Comment: `[a-z]{5-10}` doesn't seem like a strong password. Also exposing the requirement client side will allow malicious users knowledge of this.

Answer (score 2):

In my actual project page, I have the input listed like this where it contains a space between the comma and the second number in the pattern range.  When I remove this space, the input performs the length validation as expected.

Not working input with extra space after comma: 
`<input type="password" id="password" required pattern=".{5, 10}" name="password" title="Password must be between 5 to 10 characters." />`

Working input with no extra space after comma: `<input type="password" id="password" required pattern=".{5,10}" name="password" title="Password must be between 5 to 10 characters." />`

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in fiddle.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required pattern="[a-z]{5,10}" title="5 to 10 characters">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Try it on this link
https://jsfiddle.net/ammarami007/kwa72rpL/

it will accept 5 to 10 lowercase characters

Comment: When I run it in a Codepen, the validation does not fire.

Comment: @RickR.That's because he had removed the `required` attribute.